# Writing CSV file using custom Delimiter (space or tab) using DataMapper in mule esb

Tags: csv, mule, datamapper, mule-component

By using DataMapper I'm converting XML format to CSV format but problem is unable to use space or tab as delimiter. Please let me know what configuration need to be done in DataMapper component.,

XML :

```
             <OredrId>10</OrderId>
              <CustomerName>John<CustomerName>
           <OredrId >11</OrderId>
             <CustomerName>Tom<CustomerName>
```

Expected CSV format is :

```
  10 John
  11 Tom
```

Please suggest me on this.,
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chose the delimiter when creating the CSV output format. You can change it through the "Open Properties" button on the output mapping area of the properties view.
Through these, you can archive to use the tab as delimiter.

I have tried to use space as delimiter but I was not able to do it by using the UI, but I was successful by modifying the mapping file (mappings/XXX.grp):

```
<Record fieldDelimiter=" " name="OUTPUT_FORMAT_NAME"
```

Best regards,
José